# Timer doesn't run

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I am trying to set a timer for today (the date is: 4/6/2014, and if it matters, the hour is 23:25), but the timerTask is not running..

my code is the following:

```
private void makeARemainder() {
                TimerTask timerTask = new RemindAboutEvent();
                // running timer task as daemon thread
                Timer timer = new Timer(true);
                int day = dayOfMonth;
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                Date when = new Date(2014, Calendar.JUNE, 4);
                timer.schedule(timerTask, when);

            }


class RemindAboutEvent extends TimerTask {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String title = "Event is comming!";
                String messageBody = info.eventName;
                showNotification(title, messageBody);
            }
        }
```

I tried to look on previous posts, but couldn't figure out what is wrong..

EDIT:
I want to note that the activity finishes after the makeARemainder method, and the application still working, but different activity is running.

Someone can tell the reason for the timerTask not to run?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by the following code:

```
private void makeARemainder() {
                TimerTask timerTask = new RemindAboutEvent();
                Timer timer = new Timer(true);
                String when = info.eventDayOfMonth + "/" + info.eventMonth
                        + "/" + info.eventYear + " " + info.eventHour + ":"
                        + info.eventMinute;
                try {
                    timer.schedule(timerTask,
                            (new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
                                    .parse(when/* "8/6/2014 20:28" */)));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Date` is in the past. Make sure your date is in the future:

```
// Using this contructor: Date(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second)
Date when  = new Date(2014, 6, 4, 13, 45, 00); // This time is in the future for me
// or
Date nowPlus30 = new Date();
timer.schedule(timerTask, now.getTime() + 30 * 1000);
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your answer!
But, I am afraid your first method not working my friend! :(
and I want a specific date, so your second method is not very useful for my app.
Why it's not working??? I even tried not to finish() the activity and wait, without success..

Comment: Did you try the first method with a date and time appropriate for your timezone and locality? Did you try the second method just to see the timer is functioning?

Comment: I tried it now, it's not working.. :(
I am getting reallty hopeless.. 
In other activities, I have cyclic timers and they work (This timer is not cyclic).. so it's really strange.